# Excel diagram - proportional axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, diagrams

I am making 2D line diagram in Excel with year on one axis and value on the other axis. The problem is that I have several series with values with very disparate values. One serie might go from 1 to 5000 while the another contains values between 1 and 50. I would like Excel to display 50 and 5000 (and 25 and 2500 and so forth) at the same height since they both are 100 % of the max value in each serie.

Can this be done automatically or do I need to manually calculate these "percent of max value" values in separate columns in Excel myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use 2 different axis' on an Excel chart.

So as you mentioned you would need manipulate the data to show relative percentages.

Or is what  would do is keep the data clean, and create a subset using the percentage method and plot your chart with the subset, then hide the subset and show the real data next to the chart.